# how to input values in Angular component used as attribute

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to create a component and I want to use it as an attribute on a *div* to remove the component tag, but this component requires inputs. My question is how to inject those inputs.

Using a component tag:

```
<app-comp [item]="item"></app-comp>
```

What I want to achieve is:

```
<div app-comp [item]="item"></div>
```

Comment: You are confusing directive and components, get a check on Angular Directive documentation (a directive is aimed to modify the render of an element...) https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives

Comment: No mate I'm not confusing any thing.

Comment: ow didn't understand it like this, but didn't know you can change the attribute selector, great to know it :)

Comment: glade that help you to get more knowledge, what about an up arrow :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A component can have an attribute selector, in your component definition use:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'div[app-comp]'
...
```

Or simply

```
@Component({
  selector: '[app-comp]'
...
```

If you want to use it both as a tag or as an attribute, use:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-comp, [app-comp]'
...
```

The documentation reference for this is here: https://angular.io/api/core/Directive#selector

Comment: is there a possibility to not changing the selector to 'div[app-comp]', because I'm using it elsewhere without the div

Comment: Look mate, if I use the second one that means I can't use it a html tag right?

Comment: Updated my answer again :)

Comment: Can you please share a link where this is mention in the docs?

Comment: Added the documentation reference to the answer.